# Apple app store social login - app review

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app that I want to submit to the app store. The app only supports logging in using your Apple Account. However, during app submission, Apple needs to a username and password credentials for them to test the app. What can I do? Must I support email/password sign in?

Comment: If you app supports Sign in With Apple then the reviewer will be able to use their Apple ID to sign in